# Geolocalização e Fuso horário

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, geolocalização

Estou criando um site em WordPress para uma professora de Português para estrangeiros, coloquei uma página de agendamento com um calendário pra pessoa escolher data e horário para a aula, porém, como ela vai atender o mundo todo, teria que aparecer o horário, no fuso do aluno.

Lembrando que não tem função de data no calendário são apenas números que representam as horas, o que eu pensei em fazer foi o seguinte:

Pegar a localização de quem está acessando e somar com o número que representa a hora.

Mas já quebrei a cabeça nisso e não achei nenhuma solução.

Será que alguém me ajuda?

Comment: Use um timepicker em Javascript. Assim ele lê o horário no navegador de quem está acessando: http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/